# Something wrong with my implementation of SGD

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am very new to machine learning and i was trying to implement SGD to optimize single variable linear regression in numpy but it can't find the optimal parameters.

```
def sgd(alpha,x,y,params,epochs):
    m = len(x)
    cost_history = []
    for i in range(0,epochs):
        for xi,yi in zip(x,y):
            error = (params @ xi) -yi
            grad0 =  error * xi[0]
            grad1 = error * xi[1]
            params[0] = params[0] - alpha *grad0
            params[1] = params[1] - alpha * grad1
        cost_history.append(cost_func(params,x,y))
    return params,cost_history
sgd_params,sgd_cost_hist = sgd(0.001,designX,y,np.array([3,2]),5)
```

Comment: Your code does not run because data are not provided and cost_func is not defined.  You should show a reproducible code snippet for get better help.  Also, describe more precisely what your problem is (Does this get error or how the result does not make sense).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your parameter is defined as an integer.
Try again with

```py
sgd_params,sgd_cost_hist = sgd(0.001,designX,y,np.array([3.0,2.0]),5)
```

Here is a quick demonstration of the issue.

```py
b = np.array([3, 2])
print(b, b.dtype)

b[0] = b[0] + 0.1
print(b, b.dtype)

b[0] = b[0] + 1.2
print(b, b.dtype)
```

Gets:

```py
[3 2] int64
[3 2] int64
[4 2] int64
```

The value remains integer.  Due to the learning rate, the absolute value of increments tend to be below 1, so the parameter does not update.